# Algebra difficulties within an inverse stereographic projection problem

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My book has the following question: Inverse Stereographic projection.  Solve the equation 
$$x+iy = \frac{a+ib}{1-c}$$ for a, b, and c in terms of x and y.

I found a really helpful book that works out the problem here: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/earl/G2-lecture5.pdf.  The steps are at the top of the 2nd page, and for the most part, it's what I had gotten myself; however, I don't understand one step.

I just cannot figure out what magical algebra the author did to turn $x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{1+c}{1-c}$ into $x^{2}+y^{2}= -1+\frac{2}{1-c}$.

I tried splitting it into $\frac{1}{1-c}+\frac{c}{1-c}$ and then thinking of that first numerator of 1 as $\frac{c}{c}$, but factoring that didn't get me anywhere.  I tried multiplying by one imagined as $\frac{1+c}{1+c}$ or as $\frac{1-c}{1-c}$.  But I'm getting nowhere but frustrated.

What am I missing?  I think it's just algebra, not some property of stereographic projection, but I can't be sure hence the link.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The book probably used algebraic long division.

Comment: WHOA--You're a genius!  It didn't even occur to me that you could do long division with this--which is exactly what the author did.  THANK YOU, @grantfgates!  Nothing like basic algebra to blow your mind.

Answer (score 0):

As to what is happening:

$$\frac{1+c}{1-c} = \frac{c+1}{1-c} = \frac{c-1+2}{1-c} = \frac{c-1}{1-c}+\frac{2}{1-c} = -\frac{1-c}{1-c} + \frac{2}{1-c} = 1 + \frac{2}{1-c}$$

As to the why: the point here is reducing the number of occurrences of $c$, so that you can eventually solve for it. As @grantfgates already spotted, this is a division of polynomials. When you divide $(c+1)$ by $(-c+1)$ you get a quotient of $-1$ and a remainder of $2$:

$$c+1 = (-c+1)\cdot(-1) + 2$$

Divide this equation by $(-c+1)$ and you have the above, in yet another way.